# Use package go/parser to read AST of Go source code to get an interface's methods + their parameters and return types

Tags: go, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

For example, I have this interface:

```golang
type GenericServer interface {
    Echo(context.Context, *Message) (*Message, error)
}
```

And I want to get ONLY:

```
Echo(context.Context, *Message) (*Message, error)
```

I am able to find the interface and the method name using the answer to this question: [Parsing go src, trying to convert *ast.GenDecl to types.Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836358/parsing-go-src-trying-to-convert-ast-gendecl-to-types-interface)

Using spew hasn't been very helpful because I get a 3600 line dump that I am unable to make much sense of.

If possible I would prefer to stick with importing "go/ast", "go/parser", "go/token", and "go/types", and not reading the source file to use regular expressions to find the definition (since I know what the expected name of the interface is). Also, I don't want any sort of manual reflection outside of what's necessary to assert `*ast.GenDecl` or fields with `type interface{}` to `*ast.Field`/`*ast.FuncType`/etc.

Kudos for some structure that gives me access to the parameters and return types as well.

Comment: Use [ast.Print](https://godoc.org/go/ast#Print) instead of the spew package when examining the AST.    See https://play.golang.org/p/DDkUT2w3yUV

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks! Gonna try this now

Comment: @CeriseLimón Got https://play.golang.org/p/lT52FOZoj6x with the help of ast.Print. Good enough for now! (Warning: Borderline hard-coded)